# Moving averages

Tags: r, moving-average

I have daily data for over 100 years that looks like

```
01.01.1856   12
02.01.1956   9
03.01.1956   -12
04.01.1956    7
etc.
```

I wish to calculate the 30 year running average for this huge data. I tried converting the data into a time series but cant still figure out how to go about it. I will prefer a simple method that has to do with working with a data.frame.

Comment: it does not have to be a timeseries (but representing a series of observations), take a look at http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/zoo/docs/rollmean or http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/caTools/html/runminmax.html

Comment: The `TTR` package provides all the moving averages one can possibly think of.

Comment: The `movav()` function from the `prospectr` package does it as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the preparation is the difficulty considering some leapyears.
So I try to show some way for preparing, before using the already mentioned function `runmean` of package `require(caTools)`.
First we create example data (which is not necessary for you, but for the understanding).
Second I divide the data frame into a list of data frames, one for each year and taking the mean values for each year. These two steps could be done at once, but I think the separated way is easier to understand and to adapt.

```
#example data
Days        <- seq(as.Date("1958-01-01"), as.Date("2015-12-31"), by="days")
Values      <- runif(length(Days))
DF          <- data.frame(Days = Days, Values = Values)
#start of script
Years       <- format(DF$Days, "%Y")
UniqueYears <- unique(format(DF$Days, "%Y"))
#Create subset of years
#look for every unique year which element of days is in this year.
YearlySubset <- lapply(UniqueYears, function(x){
              DF[which(Years == x), ]
            })
YearlyMeanValues <- sapply(YearlySubset, function(x){
              mean(x$Values)
            })
```

Now the running mean is applied:

```
#install.packages("caTools")
require(caTools)
RM <- data.frame(Years = UniqueYears, RunningMean30y = runmean(YearlyMeanValues, 30))
```

Just if I didn't got you right at first and you want some running mean for every day within about 30 years, of course you could simply do:

```
RM <- cbind(DF, runmean(DF$Values, 365 * 30))
```

And considering your problems creating a timeseries:

```
DF[ , 1] <- as.Date(DF[ , 1], format = "%Y.%m.%d")
```

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest exploring `RcppRoll` in combination with `dplyr` which provides a fairly convenient solution to calculate rolling averages, sums, etc.

## Code

```
# Libs
library(RcppRoll)  # 'roll'-ing functions for R vectors and matrices.
library(dplyr)     # data grammar (convenience)
library(zoo)       # time series (convenience)
library(magrittr)  # compound assignment pipe-operator (convenience)

# Data 
data("UKgas")
## Convert to data frame to make example better
UKgas <- data.frame(Y = as.matrix(UKgas), date = time(UKgas))

# Calculations
UKgas %<>%
    # To make example more illustrative I converted the data to a quarterly format
    mutate(date = as.yearqtr(date)) %>% 
    arrange(date) %>%
    # The window size can be changed to reflect any period
    mutate(roll_mean = roll_mean(Y, n = 4, align = "right", fill = NA))
```

## Notes

*As the data provided in the example was fairly modest I used quarterly UK gas consumption data available via the `data` function in the `utils` package.*